# problem loading and intel pro/1000 NIC in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, intel, nic, e1000

I'm trying to get an intel pro/1000 MT server NIC working in my ubuntu desktop 13.10. With no extra configuration, the system saw the interface correctly as an intel 82545 chip and loaded the e1000 driver for it. But in the `dmesg` logs there are some errors for not being able to get the hardware MAC, this prevents this interface from working at all. The system's main board is an asus z87, and although this card uses a 64-bit pci-e interface, it's mounted on a 32bit slot (it's a supported configuration as intel says). This works in windows properly, I checked it, so there must be a driver issue, not hardware. Any suggestion on what's the problem and how to solve it?

Let me add, I tried to compile the latest e1000 and e1000e kernel modules built from source, but still have the same problem. (of course the kernel for the Ubuntu 13.10, kernel linux_3.11.0-15, has the the e1000 driver built in, not as a loadable kernel module. Is it going to work at all if I `rmmod e1000`  and `insmod /the/new/compiled/e1000.ko`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trying I found a solution. as stated in dmesg, the e1000 driver failed to verify the NIC's NVRAM checksum, so it rejected the hardware MAC and assigned zeros to the MAC. so I just assigned a valid MAC to the interface, this way the interface enabled.
the MAC assignment could be done in two ways:

either by ifconfig:

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop
ifconfig eth0 hw ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

or through /etc/networking/interfaces:

```
hwaddress ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```